# Using Kong with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, kong

I've deployed Kong on AWS using Helm. Need to terminate the SSL on the LoadBalancer. HTTP request works. HTTPS request fails with "400 Bad Request - The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error.

How to configure the Kong Proxy/LB so that things work properly? I'm ok with either HTTP or HTTPS connection behind the LB. It is a requirement for the SSL to be terminated on the LB though.

Another issue is that this creates an LB with a random DNS name. Tried setting `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations` but it doesn't work either. What is the best way to "pin" either the domain name or an IP address to the LB?

Also, this creates a legacy/classic LB. Couldn't get the k8s service to create an AWS ALB.

Helm Chart overrides:

```yaml
proxy:
  enabled: true
  http:
    enabled: true
  tls:
    enabled: true
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <my-cert-name>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
```

Installing using:

```sh
$ helm repo add kong https://charts.konghq.com
$ helm repo update
$ helm install kong kong/kong \
  --atomic \
  -n kong \
  -f overrides.yaml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to also set this in the YAML:

```
proxy:
  enabled: true
  http:
    enabled: true
    servicePort: 80
    containerPort: 8000
  tls:
    enabled: true
    overrideServiceTargetPort: 8000  # <===
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <my-cert-name>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/19b5ebeed867fc9c1ec045621181604a5f763134/charts/kong/values.yaml#L187) for reference.

Iff this leads to a redirection loop on request, go ahead and add this ENV variable to Kong's configuration:

```
    - name: KONG_TRUSTED_IPS
      value: 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```

Comment: Is there any similar solution when creating Kong proxy using yaml files.

Answer (score 0):

@bitsapien answered the question, but for completeness will include the config i used (includes the trusted_ips env variable)

```yaml
proxy:
  enabled: true
  http:
    enabled: true
    servicePort: 80
    containerPort: 8000
  tls:
    enabled: true
    overrideServiceTargetPort: 8000
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <the-cert-arn>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
env:
  trusted_ips: "0.0.0.0/0,::/0"
```